# What is the meaning of neutral zero value in the fold function of pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Here is the code snippet

```
from operator import add
iris1 = sc.textFile("./dataset/iris_site.csv")
iris1_split = iris1.map(lambda var1: var1.split(","))
iris1_split.map(lambda col:float(col[0])).fold(0,add)
```

Following is what I understood about **fold** function:

1. It's used for **aggregation**.
2. The **add** is an operator for addition of the measure data in the **index 1** column.
3. The first argument is called the **neutral zero value** as per [this post](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html). (But what does it actually mean I don't know.)
4. I tried changing the zero value with 1, 2, -2, 10 and the following increment and decrements 2, 4, -4, 20 respectively occurred.

   By observing the pattern of increment/decrements, 
   The equation seems like **result = 2*neutral_zero_value + aggregation_result**

Similar zeroValue can also be seen in the foldByKey function too.

Click here to get iris [Dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StarRider/Datasets/master/iris_site.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neutral zero value is actually an identity element of the operation. In the case that is shown above the operation is addition hence the identity element has to be 0. If it was multiplication then the identity element has to be 1.
Now why does it take neutral zero?
So, similar to fold() there is reduce(). On giving an empty collection to reduce(), it throws an exception where as fold() is already defined for an empty collection with the help of neutral zero.

**Analogy**
Imagine it as a variable sum which is initialized as 0 for doing the addition operation.

```
sum_ = 0 # here 0 is an identity element for addition
collection = [1,2,4,5]
for elem in collection:
    sum_ += elem
```

Even if you pass an empty list, the **sum_** is defined.

Similarly, for multiplication

```
prod = 1 # here 1 is an identity element for multiplication
collection = [1,2,4,5]
for elem in collection:
    prod *= elem
```

For more details see this [article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-rdd-operations-transformations-actions/). Read about reduce and fold function in it.